# Pesquisa de funcionarios, multiformularios ou formulario único?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formulário, ux, usabilidade

Estou desenvolvendo um app que deve ser disponibilizado para funcionários de uma determinada empresa, para que os próprios colegas de trabalho façam a avaliação de um (dois, três, etc.) amigos de trabalho respondendo perguntas (varias delas, quantidade configuradas também pelo setor de rh) cadastradas pelo setor de rh.

Fiquei com a seguinte duvida, faço tudo em um único formulário e uso javascript para ir mostrando um pergunta por vez, ou faço vários form, um para cada pergunta?

O funcionário deve ser capaz de para o processo parcialmente e retomar de onde parou.

Comment: Só um comentário totalmente desconectado do conteúdo técnico da pergunta: na minha humilde opinião, solicitar esse tipo de avaliação 360 dos funcionários, sem qualquer contexto (e as vezes de forma anônima), é uma *péssima prática*. Não é produtivo e não é confiável. Enfim, é só fofoca institucionalizada.

Comment: @LuizVieira, tem toda razão, mas não será sem conteúdo técnico e não será anonimo, o avaliado não saberá quem o avaliou, mas o departamento de rh saberá exatamente quem respondeu, dando assim uma avaliação do avaliador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fiquei com a seguinte duvida, faço tudo em um único formulário e uso
>   javascript para ir mostrando um pergunta por vez, ou faço vários form,
>   um para cada pergunta?

Em princípio deve ser muito ruim para a usabilidade ter vários formulários. Vai ser cansativo (e desnecessariamente inútil) do ponto de vista do usuário, ter de clicar em "Enviar" para-cada-maledeta-pergunta. Só faz sentido separar em formulários diferentes as perguntas que forem sobre assuntos distintos. Se for todo sobre o mesmo assunto, use um formulário só. Faz, entretanto, um pouco mais de sentido separar diferentes questionários para cada outro funcionário sendo avaliado.

Mostrar uma pergunta por vez não é necessariamente um problema, **se você utilizar outra forma de fornecer feedback de progresso**. O usuário precisa saber quantas perguntas ele já respondeu e quantas faltam para responder. A forma mais direta e clara de fazer isso é simplesmente colocar todas as perguntas pra ele de uma vez.

Se o formulário tem muitas perguntas, você pode usar barras de rolagem ou paginação. Não muda o fato de que vai ser percebido como um só formulário. Enfim, quero dizer que a organização e a implementação são coisas distintas.

> O funcionário deve ser capaz de para o processo parcialmente e retomar
>   de onde parou.

Isso é realmente importante, principalmente se há muitas perguntas a serem respondidas. Mas isso é outra questão de implementação. Suponha, por exemplo, que você tem um único formulário apresentado com barras de rolagem. Nada te impede de salvar o que já foi digitado para reapresentar novamente se o usuário fechar e voltar mais tarde. Agora, observe que independentemente da escolha por usar um ou mais formulários, o usuário *precisa ter feedback do que já foi preenchido*.

Se a sua implementação tiver muitas perguntas, você deveria já posicionar o questionário na primeira pergunta ainda não respondida quando o usuário acessar novamente; e, principalmente, precisa incluir alguma indicação clara de onde estão as perguntas que faltam responder. Pode usar cor, pode usar um "gutter" (tipo [o mini-mapa lateral que alguns editores de texto usam para representar a visão geral do código](https://atom.io/packages/minimap)), pode até mesmo ter a opção de filtrar somente as perguntas não respondidas. O importante é prover essa facilidade para o usuário.

Eu sei que são dicas bem genéricas, mas é o que dá pra fazer para uma pergunta igualmente abstrata. Se tiver um exemplo mais concreto, aí então é possível fazer uma análise mais detalhada.